# How to write a MySQL query for fetching counts based on time ranges?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this kind of a table:

```
userId     loggedtime
-------------------
1        2012-03-05 10:45:59
2        2012-03-05 10:04:19
2        2012-03-05 10:05:09
4        2012-03-05 10:20:24
3        2012-03-05 10:20:20
6        2012-03-05 10:30:59
7        2012-03-05 10:35:59
```

I want to select how many users logged in each 5 min interval between 10 o'clock and 11 o'clock.

I need to this kind of a result.

```
time       count
---------------
10:05        2 
10:20        2 
10:30        1 
10:35        1
```

How do I write the MySQL query for creating this kind of a result?

Comment: Not sure you can do this with SQL alone, perhaps select ordered by `userId` first and `loggedtime` second (time must be ascending), then create a new array, loop through the result set and compare the times incrementing a counter while not passing the 5 minute limit.  When you pass 5 minutes or reach a new user ID, create a new entry in the array with the user ID and counter.

Comment: What exactly are the boundaries of your intervals?  It looks as though you want to count values 10:01:00..10:05:59 as being in the range to 10:05; 10:06:00..10:10:59 as being in the range to 10:10; and so on.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct @jonathan. how can I select data between two times. For eg. If I need logged users count between past 5 mins to till this time. Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to figure out something unique to group by that will give you those 5 minute intervals.

If you take the minute in the time, and divide that by 5, then you have something unique.  For instance, you can GROUP BY CAST(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM logTime) / 5 AS unsigned) and that would give you your 5 minute intervals unique.  The /5 will divide without rounding by default.

To actually write your working query, try it in stages.

First, let's get just the minute:

```
mysql> SELECT userid, EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM loggedtime) as minute from test;
+--------+--------+
| userid | minute |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |     45 |
|      2 |      4 |
|      2 |      5 |
|      4 |     20 |
|      3 |     20 |
|      6 |     30 |
|      7 |     35 |
+--------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, let's try making a column value that's unique for each 5 minute interval you can group by.  That's the minute divided by 5 with no rounding (the above value / 5):

```
mysql> select userid, EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM loggedtime) AS minute, CAST(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM loggedtime) / 5 AS unsigned) FROM test;


+--------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| userid | minute | CAST(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM loggedtime) / 5 AS unsigned) |
+--------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|      1 |     45 |                                                     9 |
|      2 |      4 |                                                     1 |
|      2 |      5 |                                                     1 |
|      4 |     20 |                                                     4 |
|      3 |     20 |                                                     4 |
|      6 |     30 |                                                     6 |
|      7 |     35 |                                                     7 |
+--------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Finally, we group by that unique column.  This query uses MIN() and MAX() to show first and last timestamp in that interval, but you could also calculate the cutoff time if you wanted it exactly like your question.

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) AS user_count, MIN(loggedtime) AS first_time, 
MAX(loggedtime) AS last_time 
FROM test 
GROUP BY CAST(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM loggedtime) / 5 AS unsigned) 
ORDER BY last_time;
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_count | first_time          | last_time           |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          2 | 2012-03-05 10:04:19 | 2012-03-05 10:05:09 |
|          2 | 2012-03-05 10:20:20 | 2012-03-05 10:20:24 |
|          1 | 2012-03-05 10:30:59 | 2012-03-05 10:30:59 |
|          1 | 2012-03-05 10:35:59 | 2012-03-05 10:35:59 |
|          1 | 2012-03-05 10:45:59 | 2012-03-05 10:45:59 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be doing this analysis routinely, it may be worth setting up a table for your time intervals.  Judging from your sample data and required results, I'd create a table:

```
Time_Intervals
I_Start      I_End
10:01:00     10:05:59
10:06:00     10:10:59
10:11:00     10:15:59
...
10:56:00     11:00:59
```

And, indeed, it would contain 12 intervals for each hour of each day (though the wraparound for 23:56:00..00:00:59 is going to present some entertainment — it is left as an exercise for the reader!).

You can then simply use this table to generate groupings:

```
SELECT i.i_end, COUNT(*)
  FROM Time_Intervals AS i
  JOIN ThisKindOfATable AS t
    ON t.loggedtime BETWEEN i.i_start AND i.i_end
 WHERE t.loggedtime BETWEEN '2012-03-05 10:01:00' AND '2012-03-05 11:00:59'
 GROUP BY i.i_end
 ORDER BY i.i_end;
```

I used BETWEEN ... AND for the join.  An alternative design would use ranges `10:01:00 .. 10:06:00` and a join condition `t.loggedtime >= i.i_start AND t.loggedtime < i.i_end`; this handles fractional seconds better.

You may need to do some tweaking of `loggedtime` to convert it from DATE+TIME into just TIME for the join condition (maybe TIME(t.loggedtime)).  You can also adapt this to print zeroes for those intervals that have no users logging in using a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.  You might also decide to drop the seconds part of the times to simplify operations.  The variations are legion.

The primary alternative to this is to convert the given times (`t.loggedtime` values) into an interval number by some appropriate computation.  This gets into highly DBMS-specific code - the functions for manipulating time are essentially unstandardized across DBMSs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to show the 5 minute interval the user's were respectively logged in, just divide the INTEGER of the (minute / 5) and then multiply by 5.  Ex: 10:03 would round down to 0, times 5 would represent 10:00.  10:05 would be rounded to 1 * 5 = 10:05

```
select
      concat( '10:', LPAD( floor( minute( UL.loggedTime ) / 5 ) * 5, 2, '0' ) as MinuteRange,
      count(*) as LoginCount
   from
      UserLoginTable UL
   where
      UL.loggedTime between '2012-03-05 10:00:00' AND '2012-03-05 10:59:59' 
   group by 
      MinuteRange
```

Yes, its hard-coded for the example, but you could also substitute so many elements... the interval from 5 minutes to 10 or 15 (or other),  even formatting the starting '10:' (hour representation) to use:

LPAD( hour( UL.LoggedTime ), 2, '0' )

so if you did a longer time range... say 21:00:00 to 23:59:59 would show all hours within the range.

Just note.  Since your comparing to a date/time column, any query you want to utilize a 'date' portion only, be sure to include the entire day range from 00:00:00 to 11:59:59 otherwise you might miss some expected data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how can you do it right now, I must think more about your needed result. But you must use `timediff` function in Mysql

example:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2009-02-01 00:00:00', '2009-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Absolutely you must use a for loop in you MySQL query to calculate the needed result for each 5 minutes.

[Look at this too.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: Hi how can I select data between two times. For eg. If I need logged users count between past 5 mins to till this time. Do you have any Idea?

Comment: Sorry @learner, my mind is occupied right now. So I can not answer you as well as you want. But you must use CURRENT_TIME() and TIMEDIFF() functions for it. Search Google for more information on these functions in action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT
    loggedTime,  
    count(UserId)
FROM tableName
WHERE loggedTime BETWEEN '2010-11-16 10:00:00' AND '2010-11-16 11:00:00' 
GROUP BY 
round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 300), name
```

Comment: Hi Naveen. How can I select user count between Now() and past 5 mins?

Comment: if you want only last five minutes count `WHERE date_field > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)
`